# How to Upsert records with jooq?

Tags: java, jooq, upsert

I am trying to upsert the rows which I retrieved from one table of a database to the identical table in another database. Both databases are postgresql.

I just want to retrieve whole columns of the rows of the table as records and simply upsert it to the table in another database.

I have written the following code :

```
try {
            String sourceDbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sourcedb";
            String sourceDbUsername = "postgres";
            String sourceDbPassword = "admin";
            Connection sourceConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceDbUrl, sourceDbUsername, sourceDbPassword);
            Configuration sourceConfig = new DefaultConfiguration().set(sourceConnection).set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);


            String targetDbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/targetdb";
            String targetDbUsername = "postgres";
            String targetDbPassword = "admin";
            Connection targetConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(targetDbUrl, targetDbUsername, targetDbPassword);
            Configuration targetConfig = new DefaultConfiguration().set(targetConnection).set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);

            String sourceSchema = "public";
            String targetSchema = "public";

            Table<Record> sourceTable = DSL.table(DSL.name(sourceSchema, "mytable"));
            Table<Record> targetTable = DSL.table(DSL.name(targetSchema, "mytable"));
            DSLContext sourceDslContext = DSL.using(sourceConfig);
            DSLContext targetDslContext = DSL.using(targetConfig);
            String customSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + sourceSchema + ".mytable";

            Result<Record> records = sourceDslContext.fetch(customSelectQuery);
            
            for (Record record : records)
                targetDslContext
                        .insertInto(targetTable)
                        .set(record)
                        .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                        .set(record)
                        .execute();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I can see that I retrieve the records successfully.

However, somehow the record values are sent empty inside the upsert query created by jooq inside for loop and I got the following exception  :

> org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "public"."mytable" values () on conflict ([unknown primary key]) do update set [ no fields are updated ]]; ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
> Position: 40
> at org.jooq_3.16.1.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source)
> at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3089)
> at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:670)
> at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:349)
> at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDelegatingQuery.execute(AbstractDelegatingQuery.java:115)
> at Main.main(Main.java:48)
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
> Position: 40
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:153)
> at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:219)
> at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:414)
> at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.execute(AbstractDMLQuery.java:961)
> at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:335)
> ... 2 more

I appreciate for your comments.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article on [why you should use jOOQ with code generation](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/) explains why you ran into this problem. In short, without primary/unique key meta data attached to your tables, jOOQ cannot emulate the MySQL `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause on your PostgreSQL dialect.

But then again, why even use that? You're using PostgreSQL, and jOOQ has native support for PostgreSQL's `ON CONFLICT` clause (or also `MERGE` for more complex cases), so use the native syntax, instead.

Comment: Hi Lukas,
Thank you very much for your response.The role of my app will be connecting to the databases and retrieving the newly inserted or updated data and upsert it to the target databases by using the tables and databases provided by user.These stuff might be any type of table and database(just started with postgresql).As farI got, in order to achieve that, I need to associate physical table to a class within my code via jooq code generator to get the primary key for upsert operation, am I right?As everything is changeable from the app aspect, is there any way without dealing with classes?

Comment: @kocakmo: I see. In that case, this only works if you use the internal APIs that jOOQ's code generator also uses, in order to specify primary key meta data. Basically, extend `TableImpl`. As this isn't recommended or documented, I won't show an example here. But it's certainly possible to do this.